# Test of (absolute) convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have to test
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{ \frac {k^m}{m^k} } $$
for convergence and absolute convergence. m is an integer except 0.
My idea is to use the root test, so:
$$ \lim\limits_{k \to \infty}  \left|\sqrt[k]{k^m} \frac 1m \right|$$
Now I can factorise to
$$ \lim\limits_{k \to \infty} \left|\sqrt[k]{k^{m-1}} \sqrt[k]{k} \frac 1m \right|$$
In a previous exercise I have already proven that $\lim \limits_{k \to \infty}\sqrt[k]k$ converges to 1. 
If I factorise m times, there will always remain the factor $ \frac 1m $ which makes the sequence $<1$ and thus the series converges absolutely (according to the root test)
(sorry for bad english, I'm a non-native)

Is this proof consistent?

Comment: what is $m$ ? $m\in\mathbb N$ ?

Comment: m is an integer except 0, so (...-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3 ...)
(I am new to MathJax, i couldn't find the symbol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Ratio theorem, if we set $x_k=\frac{k^m}{m^k}$
$$\left|\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k}\right|=\left|\frac{(k+1)^m m^k}{m^{k+1}k^m}\right|=\underbrace{\left|\frac{k+1}{k}\right|^m}_{\to 1}\cdot \left|\frac{1}{m}\right|\to \left|\frac{1}{m}\right|\quad\text{if }k\to\infty $$

Then it converge if $|m|>1$.

Comment: The problem is that |m| could also be somewhere between 0 and 1 ...

Comment: But if $0<|m|<1$ it doesn't converge. But now you have to check what happen for $m=\pm 1$.

Comment: ah sorry, nevermind, m is an integer except 0 anyway.

Comment: then you just have to check what happen if $m=\pm 1$, because for the other $m$ it converge (like I proved).

Comment: well, didnt you already show it? it doesnt matter if m is +1 or -1 since we are treating the absolute value

Comment: No, I just show that it converge for all $m$ excepted $==1$ or $m=-1$, and acctualy it doesn't converge for $m=\pm1$.

Comment: okay, I accept your argument, in my proof I get the same problem.
Since m=1 or m=-1 is possible to choose, the series doesn't converge? Thanks

Comment: The serie doesn't converge because in fact the limite of the general term is not 0.

Comment: doesnt it converge if we take, for example, m=2?

Comment: ok course it does, I just proved it. I suggest you to review your course.

Comment: I was just irritated by your first comment. As you can see, I actually did the proof on my own, I just wanted to know if it's correct. We have the same results, so it should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

$\;m\;$ is a constant here, the running index is $\;k\;$ , so

$$\sqrt[k]{k^m}=\sqrt[k]k\,\sqrt[k]k\cdot\ldots\cdot\sqrt[k]k\xrightarrow[k\to\infty]{}1\cdot\ldots\cdot 1=1$$

and thus

$$\sqrt[k]\frac{k^m}{|m|^k}=\frac{\sqrt[k]{k^m}}{|m|}\xrightarrow[k\to\infty]{}\frac1{|m|}$$

and thus the series converges if $\;\frac1{|m|}<1\;$

Comment: that is pretty much what I meant, so would you say it's "water-proof" ?

Answer (score 0):

For $m<0$ the series converges by Dirichlet test, since 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-\frac{1}{m})^k <A
$$
and 
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} k^{-m} = 0
$$
Hence the sum of the product of $(-\frac{1}{m})^k$ and $k^{-m}$ converges.

Comment: but would you say that my proof is also legit?